# Lost all my iOS simulators and Genymotion after upgrading SDK from continuous builds

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Lost all my iOS simulators and Genymotion after upgrading SDK from continuous builds.

I tried to delete the new SDK and revert to an older SDK but those simulators are gone.  Even after plugging my devices in they won't show up as options to build to either

Anyone have any idea how I can get my simulators back?  Totally dead in the water now :(

Thanks!!

Comment: Check your cli version and other dependencies ,you can also refer this http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-SupportedSDKReleases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praise google.

Heres the answer for anyone else freaking out like I just did.

> 1) Open terminal
>
> 2) `titanium sdk select stable`